# d3.js: an animation meeting a moving object from another animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

I use D3.js to animate the movement of an object in an SVG.

As the moving object approaches its destination, I want to see lines reaching out from near the destination towards the object. These lines should grow until they reach the moving object, then stay connected to it as it continues to approach its destination.

The result should look like there are vines reaching out to touch and guide the approaching object on the last steps of its approach.

How can I do this?

Is there a way to make a transition do this directly?

If not, is there a way to tell a transition that it should use a given function to determine the coordinates of the line based on the amount of time in the transition that has already elapsed?

I imagine that the latter should look like this, but it's not working:

```
line.transition()
    .duration(durationOfGrowthAndDragging)
    .attr('x2', function(d, t) {
            frac = Math.min(1, t / timeBeforeConnectionsReachIncomingNode);
            x = x1 + (parseFloat(node.attr('cx')) - x1) * frac;
            return x;
        })
        .attr('y2', function(d, t) {
            frac = Math.min(1, t / timeBeforeConnectionsReachIncomingNode);
            y = y1 + (parseFloat(node.attr('cy')) - y1) * frac;
            return y;
        })
```